# java.util.scanner with chars

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a maze finding algorithm using object-oriented programming. I have the mazes stored in a file and I want the file to read the mazes and print them out before solving them (IK it is easier to do it other ways but I have to use a file reader). But, my charAt function does not work and I am not sure how to make the fileReader read chars. If any one could offer a solution that would be great:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static Maze maze;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<char[]> mazeArray = new ArrayList<char[]>();
        try {
            File myMaze = new File("maze.txt");
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(myMaze);
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                char[] mazeLayout = new char[(int) myMaze.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
                    for (int j = 1; j < myMaze.length(); j++){
                        mazeLayout[i] = fileReader.next().charAt(j);
                        mazeArray.add(mazeLayout);
                    }
                }
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        maze = new Maze(mazeArray);
        maze.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description. Try again. Exception? Stack trace? NB "I have to use a file reader": well, you aren't, you are using a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always nice to have sample file data to see what's in being read because at this point...I would only be guessing. If the file content looks like this:

```
xx xxxxxxx
xx  xxxxxx
xxx xxxxxx
xxxx    xx
xxxxx x xx
xxxx  x  x
xxxx xxx x
xxxxxx   x
xxxxx  xxx
xxxxx xxxx
```

then you don't need a char[] array, you can just store each line into the ArrayList which would then be an ArrayList of String (`ArrayList<String>`). Now it's just a matter of printing each element within the array list to the console window. I just don't know, so...we'll just **assume** it's like the above but we'll take each line and convert it to a char[] array because you seem to want to do this with Characters. With this in mind...

What needs to be done:

1. Read the file line by line.
2. Take each line read in and convert it to a `char` array.
3. Take this array an add it to the `mazeArray` ArrayList.
4. Print the contents of the ArrayList (`mazeArray`) to the console
   window.

```
// ArrayList to hold the Maze from file.
ArrayList<char[]> mazeArray = new ArrayList<>();

// `Try With Resources` used here to auto-close reader and free resources.
try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("maze.txt"))) {
            
    // String variable to hold each line read in
    String line;
    // Loop through the whole file line by line...
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                
        // Task 1: Apply current line read to the `line` variable.
        line = fileReader.nextLine().trim(); // Remove any leading/trailing spaces as well.
                
        // Make sure the line isn't blank (if any). You don't want those.
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;  // Go to the top of loop and read in next line.
        }
                
        // Task #2: Convert the String in the variable `line` to a char[] array.
        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
                
        // Task #3: Add the `chars` character array to the `mazeArray` ArrayList.
        mazeArray.add(chars);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(yourClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

/* Task #4: Print the maze contained within the `mazeArray` ArrayList
   to the Console Window.       */
// Outer loop to get each char[] array within the ArrayList.
for (char[] characters : mazeArray) {
    // Inner loop to get each character within the current char[] array.
    for (char c : characters) {
        System.out.print(c); //Print each character on the same console row.
    }
    System.out.println(); // Start a new line in console.
}
```